# Declare some types and use globally in a Razor/Blazor page

Tags: razor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

Sorry for the confusing title of my question, I am not sure how to make it clearer.

Let's say we have a razor/blazor pages, and it is a list of Users

Reality:

```
<component EntityType="User" .... />
@{
   var item = someAPI.get<User>(id);
}
...
@code{
   var anotherItem = new User();
   anotherItem.FirstName = "John";
   anotherItem.Price = 100; //error will be prevented at compile time;
   ...
}
```

As we can observe this page is quite "User-specific" with a lot of User as the type, and when we want to replicate it (with some modifications) for a list of Product, we need to replace the type either manually or in a batch which both are more or less error-prone. Some errors will be detected at compile time, but not always all of them.

Is there any way to declare some types in the beginning and use them in both tags and codes, so that the compiler will eventually generate finally the same thing as above?

Dream:

```
##DECLARE ITEM_TYPE = User##
##DECLARE MAYBE_ANOTHER_ITEM_TYPE = UserPreferrence##

<component EntityType="ITEM_TYPE" .... />
@{
   var item = someAPI.get<ITEM_TYPE >(id);
}
...
@code{
   var anotherItem = new ITEM_TYPE ();
   anotherItem.FirstName = "John";
   anotherItem.Price = 100; //error will be prevented at compile time;
   ...
}
```

Restriction: Such pages cannot be converted to a generic component.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want, but maybe you could start by learning about Dynamic Components and then say if they do what you want? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JIADmG2kxo

Comment: I'm with Benny1973 here.  You'll need to explain yourself a little better.  Does your last statement say you don't want to use generics?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Thanks for sharing about Dynamic Components, it is very useful in some cases. However, it does not seem to handle @ bind- parameter or Value="User.FirstName", I doubt it can do that magic. I am looking for some kind of template for .razor file itself, not that template razor provides. Imagine we have user.razor.template, which will be tranlated to user.razor, and inside the template the declared type User equals ITEM_TYPE and gets picked up by code analysis. I have seen some HTML template engine that does the similar job and also some iterating markup generation.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Sorry about the confusion. I think I want to say I expect a template at design time, not at run time. I explained a bit more to Benny. I am using generics, and I am at the point that I can make the top level generic any more. Yet I need something to reduce the efforts of coding and the possibilities of typo-mistake, because I have hundreds of data entities and hundreds of data fields respectively. Or am I looking for a feature that cannot be logically offered?

Comment: I don't know if your looking for something that can't be done, because I not any wiser about what you are trying to achieve - what's so unique about your application.  I'll sign off.

Comment: It seems to me that you've read some technique in some other framework, and in stead of learning how Blazor works, you're trying to fit THAT framework into a Blazor-shaped hole.  C# provides the use of generic types, and Blazor has Dynamic components.  If those won't work, than I have nothing to offer you.  Good luck in your programming endeavor!